# Can't unmount dmg. Keep getting "Resource Busy"

Tags: macos, dmg-image, lsof, hdiutil

"Workspace" is an encrypted dmg where I keep my code. I don't usually unmout it but I need to take a backup and it's refusing to let me unmount:

```
mark@mark-macbook-air /Volumes$ lsof | grep Workspace
mark@mark-macbook-air /Volumes$ lsof Workspace
mark@mark-macbook-air /Volumes$ hdiutil detach /Volumes/Workspace
hdiutil: couldn't unmount "disk1" - Resource busy
mark@mark-macbook-air /Volumes$ hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Workspace
hdiutil: unmount: "/Volumes/Workspace" failed to unmount due to error 49168.
hdiutil: unmount failed - Resource busy
mark@mark-macbook-air /Volumes$ ls
Macintosh HD@ Workspace/
```

If I try unmounting via the Finder:

```
"The disk “Workspace” couldn’t be ejected because “Terminal” is using it.".
```

I only have one terminal window open. It seems I could just close the terminal but since I'm pretty sure it's not using it so I ran `sudo lsof` and saw several "mds" and one "login". MDS is part of spotlight so I disabled spotlight indexing on the volume. That killed a few processes. I'm now down to just two:

```
mark@mark-macbook-air /Volumes$ sudo lsof /Volumes/Workspace/
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
login    653 root  cwd    DIR    1,5      850   29 /Volumes/Workspace/src/projectname
mds     2106 root    5r   DIR    1,5      476    2 /Volumes/Workspace
```

My question is why on earth would `login` be using my drive? Is this bad? What should I do?\

Edit: Login seems to have left the drive alone but I still can't unmount due to mds.

Answer (score 5):

You can use following command to force unmount it:

```
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Workspace -force
```

Use detach command can help to unmount and then eject the disk if you want.

If the above command reports following error message:

```
hdiutil: detach failed - No such file or director
```

It means the path is incorrect, you can use `/Volumes/Workspace/*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to `kill` or `Force Quit` the `mds` process, and if you have disabled spotlight indexing then it shouldn't start up again.